# MacBook Pro 2016 screen has interesting flickering lines

Tags: macbook-pro, display, screen

By an unknown reason, firstly:

- some pixels at edge of screen became black
- after that, flickering black lines happened from that point to other edge of screen

And when a black pixel comes over that broken point, below lines are freezing. When black pixel goes, all screen works normally. Attached image may tell the situation correctly.

[image: image of flickering lines seen in white page]

Can it require repair or may there be another solution?

Answer (score 0):

#### This is likely a hardware problem.

Flickering can be any number of issues:

- power issues like  not enough power (like a failed power rail)  or "dirty" (like a failed capacitor) power being sent to the LCD panel
- connectivity issues like signals to/from the LVDS connector are failing
- failing GPU
- failing LCD driver (chip that drives the LCD)
- failing LCD panel itself

However, the fact that you mentioned black (dead) pixels point to, at minimum, an LCD panel issue is at play here.

#### Troubleshooting Steps

You can do some steps to help confirm it's hardware:

- Boot into  [Safe Mode](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/start-up-your-mac-in-safe-mode-mh21245/mac) to rule out 3rd party software and kexts
- [Reset the SMC](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201295) (Apple Silcon, just reboot) to eliminate potential power issues
- [Take a screen shot](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201361) when the problem presents.  If the artifacts appear in the image, the problem is with the GPU (the error exists *before* it hits the display).  If not, the error is with the LCD panel.
- Run [Apple Diagnostics](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202731).  You might not get any errors generated here, but it's good to cover all your bases.

Comment: Thanks for help. I am on already 5th day of issue and some windows of programs are left frozen on screen and they haven't gone for hours. I guess it's a LCD issue too. So only it can be fixed by a technician I guess. And I couldn't run Diagnostics because of black pixel problem.